No error messages in console when using flask with telegram bot api
I am trying to develop simple telegram bot. When just started, I used polling to test the bot.
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

# decorator indicates that on_text() should be called when 
# user sends text message to the bot
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def on_text(message):
    # send message to user with uid "1" and with text '' (wrong, should cause an error)
    bot.send_message(1, '')

bot.polling()


When i send text to bot, it crashes:
A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: message text is empty

That is the intended behavior, I want my code to report errors in console.
But when I switched to flask, I noticed, that bot no longer prints any errors, moreover, it just returns on errors as if try: <sum code> except: return.
import flask


bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)
app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    if flask.request.headers.get('content-type') == 'application/json':
        json_string = flask.request.get_data().decode('utf-8')
        update = types.Update.de_json(json_string)
        bot.process_new_updates([update])
        return ''
    else:
        flask.abort(403)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def on_text(message):

    bot.send_message(1, '')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

This WILL NOT give any errors on text message, even tho it should. Just prints '1' and returns.
Only way to get errors to show in console is to put
try: 
    ...code...
except Exception as e: 
    print(e)

over everything.
Also it reports an error if I call function manually (not by decorating it with @bot.commands and etc)
I have no idea..

I am a little bit confused with your description of the code snippets' behaviours. Maybe you can indicate through comments in the snippets what were the observed behaviours in each of the snippets.

done, hope that makes sense

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The reason why the exception was not raised in webhook() is because the bot does not automatically raise any exception for you. bot.process_new_updates() will internally use worker threads by default to do its work, and when a worker encounters an exception (such as in your case), it will simply store the exception information and not propagate it. It is then up to the bot user to check for and raise the exception.
The reason why you see the exception when you use polling is because it internally checks for and raises any exception, which you are not, and should not be, doing inside webhook().
To make sure exceptions are raised you can simply make the bot run without using worker threads.
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token, threaded=False)


disabling threads does not bring error messages back, it just makes bot return status code 500 on error and that's all

That's the correct behavior. Code 500 means there is an internal error, which in this case is because flask is getting an exception when executing webhook(). If you check your flask console you should see the error printed out by flask.
